# PHP $row['value'] in a div value

Tags: php, mysql, html

Alright so I am trying to basically take what's in $row['cardid'] and set it into the value of my div tag. Then on the html file this is echoing to, it would run my function which uses that value from the div tag. Right now when I use the onclick, it pulls up but says my value is undefined. So my question is why is my variable undefined when I pull it up using html?

```
<?php
$q=$_GET["q"];
$con = mysql_connect("*", "*", "*");
if (!$con)
    {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("*", $con);
$sql="SELECT cardset, cardname, cardnumber, cardid FROM cards WHERE cardname LIKE '%".$q."%' OR cardset LIKE '%".$q."%'"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die ('Error: '.mysql_error ());

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>#</th>
<th>Cardname</th>
<th>Card Set</th>
</tr>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cardnumber'] . "</td>";
// This is the troubled line.
echo '<td><div value="'.$row['cardid'].'" onclick="changeimage(this.value)">' . $row['cardname'] . '</div></td>';
echo "<td>" . $row['cardid'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['cardset'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: please make your openingpost more clear. Which $q?

Comment: the html file uses ajax and sends filename.php?q=value

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/xAjd5) (see the [red box](http://goo.gl/NWaQx)). Instead, you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/4EBz2) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/ajrwi) or [MySQLi](http://goo.gl/NtWEM). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/RwnkO) will help you. If you care to learn, [this is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/Ja6Rk).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but you mean just something like this?

```
echo '<td><div onclick="changeimage(this.id)" id="'.$row['cardid'].'">' . $row['cardname'] . '</div></td>';
```

Use ID instead of value basically..

Example: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edwardmp/BD9Uj/)

Comment: That won't even activate my function with your supplied information.

Comment: That is bad @edwardmp. `id` can't be just numbers.

Comment: Thank you @edwardmp ! Changing it to ID made it work just like it should. Many thanks. And I will most defiantly look into changing everything to mysqli_* instead of mysql_*. Thanks again!

Comment: @edwardmp: Oh really? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_standard_id.asp - "Must begin with a letter A-Z or a-z"

Comment: I see. Thanks, you're right. He could use `echo '<td><div onclick="changeimage('.$row['cardid'].'">'. $row['cardname'] . '</div></td>';` though which is correct and should work the same.

Comment: That is also making the idea of keeping the value in a the element obsolete. Anyways, @BrettMagee, I would suggest reading the other answers as well to get the full view of the problem. Have a good day.

Comment: which makes more sense than using the value element which surely is more bad because it doesn't exist in a div..

Comment: that's what data attributes are for. BTW, down-voting me because you are pissed is immature.

Answer (score 1):

`div` elements doesn't have a `value` property, but you can get the value of the `attribute` named `value` - you should use `.getAttribute("value")`:

```
 echo '<td><div value="'.$row['cardid'].'" onclick="changeimage(this.getAttribute(\"value\")">' . $row['cardname'] . '</div></td>';
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/vaSYh/

Also, if you need to store data in DOM elements, [use `data-` attributes.](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) (Or just name them that way even if you don't have to support HTML5 right now; It will make the transition easier)

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use this.value.
It’s not a form.

Use this.innerText or this.innerHtml to get the content of the div

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly your answer, you want to alert the value of $row['cardid']?
With your code, you can't get the correct value, because you're mixing up javascript code with php code.
The 'this' keyword in your 'onclick' event handler, is the javascript function itself, then it has not a 'value' property.
Try this code, to alert the right value:

```
echo '<td><div value="'.$row['cardid'].'" onclick="changeimage('.$row['cardid'].'">'. $row['cardname'] . '</div></td>';
```